# What does the term 'grocer' mean in this song? (British usage)

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english, lyrics, songs

In the song "Waiting for Margret to Go," which is about the death of Margaret Thatcher, the artist says "Grocers and Methodists lay her down low". What is the artist referring to by "grocer"? Is it really someone who works in a grocery store?

Comment: Third News has given the best explanation of the song - but, to clarify, the **grocer** owns the store; clerks and other employees who work there are not grocers.

Comment: If you want to know the meaning of the song lyrics you're better asking on Literature SE. Otherwise, you can find grocer in a dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a reference to her [**origin**](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/margaret-thatcher-dead-how-went-1819772), and that her youth was spent working in her family shop:

> The second daughter of Alf and Beatie, Margaret Hilda Roberts was born
>   on October 13, 1925, above her father's grocer's shop in the small
>   Lincolnshire market town of Grantham.

Comment: Her father was also a Methodist lay minister, so it refers to her background in that way too, though I think it also referred to her original electoral base, that of the economically aspirational (rather than both the working-class base of Labour and the more upper-class base the Conservatives had before her) and the socially conservative.